# What is the preposition that I should put after the verb "recommend" and before object pronoun?

Tags: prepositions, pronouns

What is the preposition that I should put after the verb "**recommend**" and before an **object pronoun**?

For example:

> "I have a friend who learns English, but the problem is that he uses
>   "google translate" which is full of mistakes. I would like to
>   **recommend** (to?) **him** about a better dictionary that he can use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the correct preposition is *to*.

Often these questions can be answered with the help of a collocation dictionary, e.g. [this one](http://www.freecollocation.com/search?word=recommend).

I should say that there are other problems with your sentences. In the first one, you don't say **who learns English* but *who is learning English*. Also, you don't recommend (to someone) *about* something, but instead you recommend something: *I would like to recommend to him a better dictionary* (or *I would like to recommend a better dictionary to him*); also possible are *I would like to recommend him to use a better dictionary* and *I would like to recommend a better dictionary for him to use*.

Comment: Your answer, wasn't only a simple answer for my specific question, but also very helpful and useful for my English generally, by your extra explanation about my mistakes in my writing. In addition, I didn't know the dictionary that you recommended me, it looks great for my needs. Thank you!

Comment: I think it might also be useful to point out: "I recommend he/she/they etc. get a better dictionary" when there is no preposition. The verb recommend is not so easy to use. It is true that recommend to [pronoun] does make that issue go away. :)

Comment: @Lambie Good point!

Comment: @archimedean-point You're welcome!

Comment: @archimedean-point (But it should really be *the dictionary that you recommended **to** me* :) However, I suspect that most people would in this case leave it at *the dictionary you recommended*.)

Comment: @linguisticturn "you don't recommend (to someone) about something, but instead you recommend something" - These are possible:  I recommended the Oxford English Dictionary to him; I recommended him to use the Oxford English Dictionary.

Comment: @michael-harvey Thank you. I incorporated those into the answer.